# How to get wamp to be accessible over the network?

Tags: wordpress, apache, wamp

I have followed alot of advice online and still cant seem to get my wordpress site to be accessible online.

In my httpd.conf I have set the following:

```
#1- 
#   onlineoffline tag - don't remove
Require all granted

#2- 
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
Listen 80
```

Then in the website conf file I have something like:

```
Alias /MyTestWebsite/ "C:/Users/myUser/Google Drive/Work/Me/Wordpress/" 

<Directory "C:/Users/myUser/Google Drive/Work/Me/Wordpress/">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all

Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When i access the site locally it works fine. When i access the site using my IP (192.168.0.2/MyTestWebsite/) on my local machine this also works fine. However when i type in the laptop 192.168.0.2/MyTestWebsite/ it just times out. If i enable port 80 on the firewall (which I dont really like doing at all) then I just get a Not Found error.

When i ping 192.168.0.2 from the laptop, it pings fine. Does anyone have any ideas here as to what else I can try here? Are there any other easier ways to set this up I have been at this for a while now!?

Thank you :)

Comment: Its a much better idea to use Virtual Hosts rather than Alias's. [See this post for help setting up a Virtual Hosts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23665064/project-links-do-not-work-on-wamp-server/23990618#23990618) for each of your projects

Comment: Thanks for this, I did have a look into this earlier and the reason why I opted not to use virtual hosts is because I would have to add a line to the laptop's hosts file to point the IP of the PC to the virtual host - This is fine on a laptop but a pain if i want to add it to mobile devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this problem was just to install the wamp directory directly into the google drive folder which would be the root directory. Not ideal because it means sql and wamp folder would get uploaded to google drive too which are about 500mb but this solution will do for now.

The other solution was to use virtual hosts but that involves editing the hosts file on every network laptop/pc/phone you want to run it on so that the virtual host points to the IP of the PC running wamp.

I still find it very strange that aliases work fine on the same machine wamp is running on but when other machines on the network try to access wamp, the alias just gets ignored but if anyone can explain why, please let me know.